# Breakfast Cereal on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, eating, dairy

Is it permissible to eat cereal in cold milk on Shabbos? I am aware that oats and finely ground baby food is permissible if done in a certain way. I am referring to chunky cereals such as corn flakes for example.

Comment: Why would you think yes or no? Please [edit] that in so we can address your concerns better.

Comment: I'm uncertain which prohibitions may concern you. I'm surmising one of them may be "lash" - kneading as the flakes get mushy? This is incidental and you have no intent or benefit from this. As a general rule, "incidental" occurrences such as these are not of concern. You need to edit your question so we know what the concerns are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is totally permissible no matter how you do it. The relevant concern here is that it's prohibited to "knead" by mixing flour with water to make dough. (That's why making a mush like baby cereal is a bit tricky; it's supposed to be made far thinner than bread dough, and made differently as well.) Corn-flakes-in-milk doesn't look anything like a bread dough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There's no reason to prohibit that I can think of; a glance at a laws-of-*Shabas* book reveals no prohibition; and the common practice  (in my own limited experience) is to allow it.